# Calling wpf signalr client methods from outside hub in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, signalr

```
public async Task ApplyChangedSettings()
{
    if (ConnectionTimeEntryHub.State == Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Connected)
    {
        var d = await HubProxy.Invoke<TimeEntryV2.Models.Models.UpdatingSettings>("GetSettings", User.UserIdentity);
        TimeEntrySettings = d;
    }
}
```

Above method is created in wpf client viewmodel , I want to call this method from class outside hub in my asp.net web application as per documetation

```
var hubContext = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TimeEntryHub
s.TimeEntrySettingsHub>();
if (TimeEntryHubs.TimeEntrySettingsHub.Users.Any(f => f.Value == userId))
{
    var connectionID = TimeEntryHubs.TimeEntrySettingsHub.Users.Where(f => f.Value == userId).Single().Key;
    hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionID).ApplyChangedSettings();
}
```

I am getting hub context as above , but its not doing anything ,It gets executed silently without any errors and does not reflect any changes

I stepped through the code its not calling the method on .net client , breakpoint on client method is not reached

Comment: Can you show how you have registered for the event on the client?

Comment: Yes , I did not registered for the event , I corrected it and used On Method of hubproxy to register for the event ApplyChangedSettings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dependencyresolver solved my problem

on Server Side

```
var dependencyResolver = GlobalHost.DependencyResolver;
var connectionManager = dependencyResolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
var hubContext = connectionManager.GetHubContext<TimeEntryHubs.TimeEntrySettingsHub>();

   if (TimeEntryHubs.TimeEntrySettingsHub.Users.Any(f => f.Key == userId))
      {
        var connectionID = TimeEntryHubs.TimeEntrySettingsHub.Users.Where(f => f.Key == userId).Single().Value;
        hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionID).ApplyChangedSettings();
      }
```

On client Side

```
HubProxy.On("ApplyChangedSettings", () =>   ApplyChangedSettings().ConfigureAwait(false));

public async Task ApplyChangedSettings()
 {
   if (ConnectionTimeEntryHub.State == Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            await ApplySettings().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
 }
```